# Airflow - Xcoms and parallel jobs - problem (xcoms overwriting themselves)

Tags: airflow

I have the pipeline below. On my 2nd level of tasks (first paralel tasks) I write a Xcom with some ID, then in the 3rd (2nd col. in paralel) and 4th column of tasks (3rd in paralel) I retrieve the xcoms I wrote in column two. The problem is that since it's writing 6 tasks at the same time, the XCOM that sticks in the end is the last one that was written.

Is there a way for me to make these Xcoms work in parallel? by now because of this problem I have to run all of theses tasks linearly, so the xcoms work correctly...
Image can be seen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXFWz.png

Comment: Your image didn't attach

Comment: I would create a more granular Xcom key, include the date-time of the task/dag in question and that's probably good enough

Comment: the problem with putting the timestamp in the key is: how would the guys who pull (receive) the xcoms going to know from which of the key-timestamp they should get the value from? or do you think airflow would just take care of it for me? guess I can't show images because i have less than 10 points here.

Comment: Airflow provides context variables as part of every DAG execution that include timestamps. these can be passed into your various task operators and used there to pull Xcoms